# Symfony2: Where/how I can trigger my own annotation-reader?

Tags: php, routes, annotations, symfony

I want read custom annotations like @Route for Controllers. I will use it for eventlisteners like this:

```
/**
 * @Event("some.event");
 */
public function onSomeEvent(Event $event) {}
```

I found out, I can use an annotation-reader or simple php-reflections for analysing the docblock. Which event I should listen to to trigger my reader? Or can someone give me a hint how it works with @Route-annotations? I need almost the same logic, but I missed obviously some important points by reading the symfony code.

Comment: Depends on when you need to read them. Before a controller is called, after, or inside controller? Clarify your question.

Comment: I need it early as possible and before the controller is called, because I want configure the eventdispatcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the code in the `ControllerListener` [class](https://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/EventListener/ControllerListener.php) within [SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](https://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle). It is registered as a `kernel.event_listener` [here](https://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/annotations.xml).

This listener reads/parses the annotations provided by that bundle. The annotations provided by SensioFrameworkExtraBundle are located [here](https://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/tree/master/Configuration).

You should be able to simply mimic one of the bundle's provided annotations to accomplish your needs.